# How to practice a Revolving Pull-up Bar

Tags: exercise, training, pull-ups

How can I practice on [Revolving Pull-up Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE-YAup7gCo). I do well in regular Pull-up Bar (~30 pull ups). What is the best way to practice and what is the step by step protocol to train myself for using Revolving Pull-up Bar that is located in public park?

Comment: What exercises do you want to do on it?  There are many different exercises possible.

Comment: Since I'm beginner, I would like to know how to start training with the easiest and most basic one and how to progress to more advanced.

Comment: Doesn't it say like right in the video you posted? They have all the basic advice regarding technique and how to progress right there